# Why Is + not being replaced in javascript string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is my syntax correct i wanted to replace string in pattern abcd+abcd+ but its not working using replace method in JavaScript here is the code snapshot 
the commented one dose not work which i require

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerText;
  //var res = str.replace(/+/g, "red");
  var res2 = str.replace("+", "red");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = res2;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>
<p id="demo">Mr + has a + house and a blue car.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: already tried above
https://jsfiddle.net/h52pad7y/

Comment: What do you want to change the `+` or `blue`.?

Answer (score 2):

The commented-out portion is nearly right, but you need to escape the `+` because it's a special character in regular expressions:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").textContent;
  var res = str.replace(/\+/g, "red");
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent= res;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>
<p id="demo">Mr + has a + house and a blue car.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

`innerText` is a quirky nonstandard property that IE introduced. It is highly recommended to instead use the standard, quicker, more reliable `textContent` instead - see http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText

Comment: thank you CertainPerformance